# Not able to generate log file name with correct date format

Tags: java, log4j

Here is the properties file:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file ,stdout

    # Direct log messages to file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
    log4j.appender.file.File=d:/logs/example1  
    log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n 
    # Direct log messages to stdout
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

I want to generate new log file while date
    change for that i used DailyRollingFileAppender.
    Actually it's generating file log file and changed
    previous file name but format of date is like 
    this "log.२०१६-१२-३०" but i    want     this name as
    "example1.2016-12-30".
    I am using log4j1.2.17 and java1.7.can some one help me.

Comment: I got solution just changed System date format from Hindi(India) to English(India)